# What would be the best way to simulate the animation on the iPhones home screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, controllers

I have two view controllers and i can manage the right to left animation between them via a custom segue, but what would be the best way to have the incoming VC animate with the finger, kind of like how the home screen on the iphone works?

If this is confusing, I mean to say when you drag your finger right to left on the iPhones home screen, there is a point while you are dragging with your finger where you can see the right half of the first view, and the left half of the second view, the natural action of 'dragging' the 2nd view onto the screen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen it described that functionality that resembles the springboard (iphone home screen) is not really separate view controllers, but a single, wide view.

So for the functionality you want to implement, you might want to think about approaching it differently, with a single view controller to swipe between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Page Control, here are some tutorials you may like looking at:
- [Cocoa with Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html) 
- [Page Control](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right,you can easily achieve this effect by adding your tableviews to a **UIScrollView** with pagination enabled.Check this tutorial,[tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.